# What do these errors mean ? mysql in django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am trying to run a program I was given to look at as an example, it is like a shopping website, that uses MySQL database instead of the original database provided in Django! I just wanted to see if anyone understands what these errors mean? any info would be appreciated! I would have provided the code of the web page, but there is to much it won't fit !

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 374, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/model_checks.py", line 30, in check_all_models
    errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1266, in check
    errors.extend(cls._check_fields(**kwargs))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1337, in _check_fields
    errors.extend(field.check(**kwargs))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 893, in check
    errors = super(AutoField, self).check(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 208, in check
    errors.extend(self._check_backend_specific_checks(**kwargs))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 311, in _check_backend_specific_checks
    return connections[db].validation.check_field(self, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 41, in check_field
    field_type = field.db_type(connection)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 629, in db_type
    return connection.data_types[self.get_internal_type()] % data
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 183, in data_types
    if self.features.supports_microsecond_precision:
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/features.py", line 54, in supports_microsecond_precision
    return self.connection.mysql_version >= (5, 6, 4) and Database.version_info >= (1, 2, 5)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 367, in mysql_version
    with self.temporary_connection() as cursor:
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 564, in temporary_connection
    cursor = self.cursor()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 231, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 204, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 171, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 263, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 193, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'abc'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

Comment: read the last line

Comment: The MySQL user you configured in your settings is not allowed to access your MySQL database. This is written in plain text in the last line.

Answer (score 0):

This means the connection string (in Django the database credentials) you are using to connect to your MySQL database are WRONG. Check your username, password, host, port, DB name in settings.py and ensure that your database is accepting connections from your server.

Answer (score 0):

Check settings.py

```
 DATABASES = {
     'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'djangocrud',
        'USER':'root',
        'PASSWORD':'pass$123',
        'HOST':'127.0.0.1',
        'PORT':'3306',
    }
}
```

Maybe you needthis
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATABASES